# How to get the raw data form a buffer in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm very new in nodejs and I'm trying to implement a file (CSV format) upload requirement using API Gateway and Lambda. Here is my nodejs code in my lambda function to buffer the body of the request which is coming from the API Gateway:

```
let bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(event['body-json'], 'base64');
```

when I log the `bodyBuffer` I am seeing the whole body request:

```
2018-04-04T22:30:26.637Z    c56d1263-3857-11e8-ba40-c1378697db16     
bodyBuffer: -----------------------------153501500631101
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedFile"; filename="sampleData.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

id,firstName,lastName
1,john,doe
2,jane,doe
-----------------------------153501500631101
```

Then I try to grab the CSV data from it:

```
let json = JSON.stringify(bodyBuffer);
```

but it looks like this:

```
{
"type": "Buffer",
"data": [
    45,
    45,
    45,
    45,
    45,
    45,
    45,
    45,
```

I got trouble to get the right csv data here. Can anybody help please?

Comment: Well, `45` is your hyphens that start the MIME part.  If you want the actual data inside the MIME part, you will need some code that parses MIME for you to give you just the data inside the MIME parts.  You don't show where this data comes from.

Comment: @jfriend00 is there any other way to get the actual data from the 'bodyBuffer'?

Comment: If it's a `Buffer` object, you can call `bodyBuffer.toString()` to get the string representation of the whole body.  You will still have to parse the MIME to get to the content of the MIME part.  In the future, you might want to look at the [Buffer doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `Buffer.toString()`. Ideally you would want to download the file at the client side, in that case the headers for `Content-Type` can be set as 'application/vnd.ms-excel'.
The response can be read by `Buffer.toString('base64')`